# Extract and read JSON Data from web API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What I'm working on is providing 1 line instant definitions of terms and perhaps one line answers to few logical questions. Suppose a user inputs "JavaScript" and JavaScript visits the url https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=JavaScript&format=json&pretty=1, gets the item "Definition" (Look at the API link to understand, Definition is in the first line itself) and displays its value of Definition and alert the user with the required data.

Anyways my code currently is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hi</title></head>
<body>
<input id="ddgAPI"><button>Search</button>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I've not put in the required JavaScript/jQuery code as I'm confused with this. Thank you :)

Comment: Yiu should put a jsfiddle of what you have tried before asking others to do it for you?

Comment: Okay, plain answer would be appreciated too.

Comment: The only question you've asked is: _Suppose a user inputs "JavaScript" and JavaScript visits the url https://api.duckduckgo.com/?_  which isn't much of a question.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is a cross-domain request you can only do this with a proxy or with JSONP. Fortunately [DuckDuckGo supports JSONP](https://duckduckgo.com/api), so you just need to ensure that you add a callback parameter to the URL request like:

```
https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=JavaScript&format=json&pretty=1&callback=jsonp
```

... or use the appropriate jsonp parameter with jQuery's ajax method, something like:

```
$('#ddgAPI').on('keyup', function(e) {

  if (e.which === '13') {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.duckduckgo.com/',
      data: { q: $(this).val(), format: 'json', pretty: 1 },
      jsonpCallback: 'jsonp',
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Okay, I said JavaScript in the q parameter as an example. To put the value of q parameter what the user enters what should I enter?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It says that when the user clicks the return button in the input box the ajax will fire with the input box value as the q parameter. I've not tested it, but it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to talk to the remote service. `url` should be `https://api.duckduckgo.com`. `type` should be `GET`. `data` should be:

```
var data = { q:'JavaScript', format:'json', pretty:1 };
```

jQuery will then compile everything into an AJAX request, send it to the server. Pass a function as `success` so you can do something with the result:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.duckduckgo.com",
    type: "GET",
    data: { q:'JavaScript', format:'json', pretty:1 },
    success: function(data) {  $('#output').html(data); }
});
```

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9DCm/) failed as suspected:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=JavaScript&format=json&pretty=1. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:1