# how to call external json url and access it values

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

This returns a json object

```
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/search?api_key=youAPIKey&name=radiohead
```

i tried this way but didn't work.

```
function cc() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/search?api_key=APIKey&name=radiohead",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

how can i call this url and access the object values using java script or jquery.

Comment: is this url on the same domain?

Comment: Duplicate of [Extract and read JSON Data from web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573528/extract-and-read-json-data-from-web-api) and so many others...

Comment: @KhanhTO no not in same domain

Answer (score 0):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you can't access a resource on a different domain.

The solution is to proxy the request through a server side script on the same domain as your Javascript. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is an option but only if the third party supports it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by MrCode, you will need to use JSONP to access the data as your script is running in a different domain.

Echonest supports JSONP, using the `format` and `callback` options. You need to amend your url to include the `format` option.

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/search?api_key=FILDTEOIK2HBORODV&name=radiohead&format=jsonp

If you amend the `dataType` option in your ajax options to `jsonp` then jQuery will append a `callback` parameter, which Echonest will use when sending the data back to you. You can then access the data in your success handler as required.

Unfortunately, you have posted your API key in your question, which means that lots of Stack Overflow users may be looking at your link, and screwing your access limit. You may need to wait for this question to become unpopular before your rate limit drops off again.